# theoretical results on the conditioning of numerical eigenvalue problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question I am working on is as follows. A is an $n\times n$ matrix. A is diagonalizable by a similarity transformation s.t. $T^{-1}AT=B ={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n). $  $\tilde{A}=A+{G}. $ 
If $\tilde{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $\tilde{A},$ show
$$ \|(B-\tilde{\lambda}I)^{-1}T^{-1}{\bf G}T\|_p\geq 1. $$

My strategy was to use algebra to solve for the left side matrix and then calculate all of the possible norms for it. $\tilde{\lambda}$ and $\lambda$  happened to cancel out nicely, but this does not incorporate using the opposite to show $\tilde{A}-\tilde{\lambda}I$ is invertible.

The hint is generally confusing and am not sure to do what with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To incorporate your professor's hint: if the opposite is true, then there is a value of $p$ for which we have
$$
\|(B-\tilde{\lambda}I)^{-1}T^{-1}{\bf G}T\|_p < 1
$$
However, note that $(\tilde A - \tilde \lambda I)$ is invertible if and only if $T^{-1}(\tilde A - \tilde \lambda I)T$ is invertible, and
$$
T^{-1}(\tilde A - \tilde \lambda I)T = \\
T^{-1}((A + G) - \tilde \lambda I)T = \\
(T^{-1}AT^{-1} - \tilde \lambda I) + T^{-1}GT = \\
(B - \tilde \lambda I) + T^{-1}GT
$$
This matrix will be invertible if and only if the matrix
$$
(B - \tilde \lambda I)^{-1}[(B - \tilde \lambda I) + T^{-1}GT] = \\
I + (B - \tilde \lambda I)^{-1}T^{-1}GT
$$
is invertible.  Now, use the fact that $I + M$ will be invertible whenever $\|M\| < 1$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$.